# Wordpress custom single post page

Tags: wordpress

so i need to create a custom single post page in wordpress according to a client's specification on a mock up of the page. It's gotten quite difficult trying to customize the single post page of the theme i'm currently using. What can i do to make the single post page look exactly like the one in the mock up because both look way different from each other. This is the [mock up of the proposed page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZgYur.png)

Comment: You may use custom template for custom single post based on template hierarchy - https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/ let me know if this make sense

Answer (score 0):

You have to options either you can goto child theme and customize your post template single.php or like example (themes\twentyseventeen\single.php)(themes\twentyseventeen\template-parts\post\content.php) and apply your design there or you can create new template for single post. 
New template

```
<?php
/*
 * Template Name: New Template
 * Template Post Type: post
 */

 get_header();  ?>

// your html design and content of post
// along with the post loop

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```